# Elastic Search with Mongoose - Embedded Schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose, elasticsearch

I have the following mongoose schema:

```
var ReviewSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    details: String,
    user: {type: ObjectId, ref:'User'},
});

var SubjectSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    website: {type: String, index: { unique: true }},
    review: {type: [ReviewSchema], es_indexed:true}
});
```

I have another `User` schema which is referenced in `Review`.

I tried [mongoosastic](https://github.com/jamescarr/mongoosastic) plugin but I can't find ways to index the referenced schema. I want to index the name of the user of a review. So I just used elastic search client for this.

Every create/update/delete of review, I looked up in the database and update elastic search index with the value retrived from database. Is there better way for this on updating index when embedded schema is updated? Thanks

Comment: In such cases, i am using embedding document. You can embed user schema to review schema. user: {type: User, required: true}. Or you can only insert username of the user in to user field of ReviewSchema. If you need to get detailed information of user, you can get it by using username information.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using [mongoosastic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoosastic), There is a option in populate like in `Mongoose` in `mongoosastic`, using which you can index mongoose references.

```
ReviewSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
  populate: [
    {path: 'User', select: 'name'}
  ]
})
```

You can find more info about this in the documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoosastic#indexing-mongoose-references).

Comment: it's also worth pointing out that you need `es_schema` and potentially `es_select` in the mongoose model definition.